# Infer single interface from type union containing multiple interfaces

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I'm working on a project for someone where they can search through their list of licenses for each product they make, and see the different details of each license along with the Features each license allows (those features are different for each license).

This is my current solution but I feel like it could be better, Then I just pass in result as the type into LicenseData which currently accepts a generic for Features.

I have `BaseLicense` interface interface (which contains generic information when the initial license search is done) and a `SingleLicense` which extends `BaseInterface` and has additional properties. The Single License is where my type union comes into play. I am trying to get my `features` property to infer which `LicenseType` interface it needs to use based of a string variable that is grabbed when a single license is selected.

***Below is sample code because my work is secure and under NDA***

```js
//`licenses.d.ts`
export const product = { Lic1: "" };

type StringTupple = [string, string];
type StringNumberTupple = [string, number];
type LicenseType = Lic1 | Lic2 | Lic3 | Lic4 | Lic5;
type Product = typeof product;
type Result = Extract<LicenseType, { type: `${keyof Product}` }>;

interface BaseLicense
{
    Created: Date;
    Id: string;
    ProductId: number;
    ProductName: string;
}

interface SingleLicense<T> extends BaseLicense
{
    Data: LicenseData<T>;
    WorkOrder: string;
}

interface LicenseData<T> extends SingleLicense<T>
{
    Features: T;
    LicenseId: string;
}

interface Lic1
{ 
    readonly type: "Lic1";
    Endpoints: StringTupple[];
}

interface Lic2
{ 
    readonly type: "Lic2";
    Ips: string;
    System: { Users: number, Computers: number };
}

interface Lic3 
{ 
    readonly type: "Lic3";
    Legacy: string;
    LegacyMode: number;
    Demo: number;
    Filter: { Max: number, Pooling: number, Databases: number };
}

interface Lic4
{ 
    readonly type: "Lic4";
    State: number;
    Clients: number;
    Users: number;
}

interface Lic5 
{ 
    readonly type: "Lic5";
    Items: StringTupple[];
    Values: StringTupple[];
}
```

Screenshots in ID that my current solution is working, but I want to improve on it

- `LicenseType` is a Union [image]
- `Results` does become `Lic` based of my current solution [image]

Comment: Could you please [edit] the code into a [mre] with no typos or undeclared types? You've got `LicenseData`, `LicensesData`, `LicenseType`, `LicenseTypes`; and `LicenseType` is either generic or non-generic depending on which part of the code I'm looking at. I can't tell if those are typos or missing things.  I'm also concerned that your `//Properties` means that I can't reproduce because all those things are empty so it's impossible to distinguish them structurally. ...

Comment: ... The hope is that I could just paste your code into an IDE and get to work doing something instead of spending effort just getting to the starting line.  If you do decide to edit and want me to take another look, please comment and mention @jcalz to notify me. Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz I will update the code with examples, I will just have to change all the property names and interface names to be generic examples names.

Comment: You might want to test your example code in an IDE before posting it, to make sure that it demonstrates your issue.  You also don't need *five* interfaces for the example; I imagine three is sufficient to demonstrate what you're trying to do.  Also, I will not be notified when you edit, so if you want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment after you do so.

Comment: @jcalz yes it works in my IDE, all I did was update the code with my current code which works, but I feel like it is not optimal. I just changed property names to something not important. Included screenshots as well as proof that it is currently working with my current solution.

Comment: Okay, with `type Result = Extract<LicenseType, { type: \`${keyof Product}\` }>;` you're doing it the way I would do it.  Do you have a concrete reason why you think it's not optimal?  In what way could it be better?  Right now my answer, if I wrote one, would say "this is fine" (which isn't much of an answer, and makes me think this might be more of a code review question than a Stack Overflow question).  Let me know (@jcalz to ping me).

Comment: @jcalz There is no concrete reason, doing type inference like this is very new to me.  I have been using typescript heavily for the past 6 months or so, and this was the next step. I was more so wondering if there was a way for me to pass a string where "type" was compared to having to pass an object where the key of the object is what determines the type

Comment: To me `Extract<LicenseType, { type: \`${keyof Product}\`>` and having to pass an object which I would have to make conditionally compared to using a string which I already have access to from the `BaseLicense` `ProductName` property doesn't seem optimal

Comment: I'm really not following what you're saying, now, sorry.  What "object" are you "passing"?  (Oh, by the way, I guess I would write just `{type: keyof Product}` unless you have a reason why you are serializing the keys to strings.)  The more I look at this the more I think you're asking for an opinion/code review and that this question probably belongs elsewhere (*possibly* at  codereview.stackexchange.com, but they have their own requirements for what constitutes a good question).

Comment: Gotcha, and I just never changed it back from when I was trying to use  `const product = "Lic1;` as a string instead of and object and using instead of `keyof Product`. I originally had it as `Extract<LicenseType, { type: `${product}`>` which through an error. And I will look at codereview.stackexchange.com and look at possible posting there. Thank you!